# Void * pointer to a structure

Tags: c++, c, struct, void-pointers

I am implementing a timeout . So i declared a timeout structure

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned long * Task;
    unsigned long Timeout;
    unsigned long Offset;
    DATA * Next;
    DATA * Previous;    
} TIMEOUT;
```

and i initialized it to :

```
TIMEOUT Timout = {NULL ,30,0,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

and i declared another structure `DATA  Contents;`:

```
typedef struct{
    char CallBack;
    void * Data;
}DATA;
```

However when i do `Contents.Data = Timout;` it gives me the following error :

```
CA850 error E2524: illegal type combination for '=' (void *, __faked63)
```

help please :)

Comment: Your initialization for `Timeout` should not even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pointer. The expression `Contents.Data = Timeout;` tries to assign a vaue of type `TIMEOUT` to a variable of type `void*`. Use `&Timeout` to obtain a pointer:

```
Contents.Data = &Timeout;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the struct itself to the void* but the address of it so use

```
Contents.Data = &Timeout;
```